# SAP UI5 - Resource Bundle

Tags: sapui5

What is a Resource Bundle in SAP UI5 & how it works? I have tried with formatter.js (Custom formatter) and tried to read the text from the i18n file for which I got the error Resource bundle is not defined.

var resourceBundle = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();

Comment: In simpler terms, Resource Model is used to achieve language switching (via i18n texts). Check out the below links

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel 

https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/df/86bfbeab0645e5b764ffa488ed57dc/content.htm?no_cache=true

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this is defined in manifest.json, and the relevant parts of this file will look like this:

```json
{
    "sap.app": {
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        ...
    },
    ...
    "sap.ui5": {
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "your.package.name.i18n.i18n" <- Change your.package.name
                }
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved the error by creating an object for the i18n model in the component.js file.

```
var i18nModel = new ResourceModel({
bundleName: "Aggregation_binding.Aggregation_binding.i18n.i18n",
supportedLocales: [""],
fallbackLocale: ""
});
this.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
```

Comment: The UI5 way would be to declare this bundle in the manifest.json